# Function which return dictionary of arguments in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, args, keyword-argument

Function `func(*args, **kwargs)` should return dictionary, and all elements of that dictionary should be numeric or string variables. 
If argument of function is dictionary, then function should return dictionary with all elements of argument dictionary, and other arguments.
For example:

```
arg1 = { 'x': 'X', 'y': 'Y' }  
arg2 = 2
arg3 = { 'p': arg1, 'pi': 3.14 }
func(arg2, arg3, arg4=4)
```

should return this:

```
{ 'x': 'X', 'y': 'Y', 'arg2': 2, 'pi': 3.14, 'arg4': 4 }
```

How to do that? Recursion is not desirable.

Comment: A function `func(*args)` won't be able to determine and return the name `arg2`!

Comment: Is the p key of arg3 missing ?

Comment: @Tbaki it's not missing, arg3 is dictionary so we have to go deeper and find out if there are numeric or string elements in arg3.

Comment: @deceze there is locals() function where names of arguments could be determined, am I wrong?

Comment: No, `locals` won't help you. Only a stack trace would, but please for the love of all that is holy don't go there.

Comment: OK, i didn't consider that. But what if as *args could be given only dictionaries?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star/asterisk) and \* (star/asterisk) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this - but that solution needs argument numbers ascending (arg1, arg2, ..., argN).

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    res = {}
    for i, a in enumerate(args):
        if isinstance(a, dict):
            res.update(a)
        else:
            res['arg%s' % (i+1)] = a
    res.update(kwargs)
    return res


arg1 = { 'x': 'X', 'y': 'Y' }  
arg2 = 2
arg3 = { 'p': arg1, 'pi': 3.14 }

myDict = func(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4=4)
print(myDict)
```

returns:

```
{'x': 'X', 'y': 'Y', 'arg2': 2, 'p': {'x': 'X', 'y': 'Y'}, 'pi': 3.14, 'arg4': 4}
```

Comment: That's pretty close. One more thing i would like to be there is the element with key `'p'` unpacked. Variables with same names should be in in  `myDict` only if their values are the same, if that's not the case then neither of them should be there.

Comment: This should be done before you pass the args to the function ... I mean, when you create the arg-variables.

Answer (score 1):

When you pass arg2 to the function, the function does not know that it was named arg2 when you passed it in, it just know its value is 2. You would have to get stack trace to know who called that function, scrape source code to get the name and then it would be simple.

But what if I call it like this:

```
func(2)
```

what output do you expect then?

Comment: *"and then it would be simple"* – For special definitions of "simple"… ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I am new in python, so don't blame me.  What if as *args could be given only dictionaries?

Comment: read about update method of class dict: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/dictionary_update.htm

Comment: That isn't what I've been focused on. Maurice gave simple solution.